# Randomly create files and folders size of in 1M, 10M, 100M, 1G, 10G

Tags: bash, dummy-data

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution for this.

Insida a folder, how could I create random files and folders that will be size of in 1M, 10M, 100M, 1G, 10G. Each created folders also needs to have a randomly created file in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `dd` with different file sockets, e.g. `/dev/random` or `/dev/zero`.

This will create a 2MB file with random data in it:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.out bs=1M count=2
```

Or create a 1MB file from `/dev/zero`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.out bs=1024 count=0 seek=1024
```

There are a lot of examples out there, just search for "linux dd create file size". This should be wrapped in a script that will create the directories and files for you. I would think of something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#create files of 1, 10, 100 and 1000MB in size
for fSize in 1 10 100 1000
do
#create a file for size 1MB*fSize
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.out bs=1024 count=0 seek=$((1024*fSize))
done
```

Combined with another script that will create the directories and another `fSize` loop it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This Will Make a 1gb file :

```
mkfile -n 1g /location/to/folder/
```

Comment: Take a look at this site : http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/31/create-large-file-mac-os-x/